# Problem with IntelliJ -> Cannot create class with name "Main"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

Title states my problem, i get this error message:

> Cannot Create Class   Unable to parse template "Class"
>
> Error message:
> Selected class file name 'Main.java' mapped to not java file type
> 'Files supported via TextMate bundles'

Anyone got any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: This probably won't fix your problem, but you really should not name a class `Main`.

Comment: @Nexevis Why is it important to not name the main class Main? Do you believe there is a conflict or anything? The name isn't reserved in Java.

Comment: @Paul Stelian The problem does not stem from being literally unable to do it, the problem is that your names should _mean_ something related to its functionality, and calling it `Main` does not tell you at all what it does.  You can also name variables `with_underscores`, but it doesn't mean you _should_.  Other than that, I also think people learning Java could get confused by it, and think the `main` method needs to be inside of  a `Main` class because of what they learned in classes.

Comment: @Nexevis So should the main class always be named after the program/tool itself? Maybe it sometimes does make sense to be called Main because it's only there for the main method and it calls methods of other classes for the most part. Of course it depends on a case-by-case basis, what I'm saying is you shouldn't religiously _avoid_ the `Main` name for the main class. Pick the proper name always, sometimes that indeed could be `Main` lacking other good options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the [File Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html). It looks like `Main.java` file name or extension was mapped to the wrong file type by accident (`Files supported via TextMate bundles`). Remove the invalid type mapping to fix the problem. The name/extension should be mapped to Java files instead (the default setting).

See if [disabling](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) **TextMate bundles** plug-in helps.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need "Edit" button at all. Instead you need to use "-" (Minus) button in Registered Patterns area:

Select required file type in top list (Recognized File Types) -- do it for "Text files"
In bottom list (Registered Patterns) select undesired pattern -- "SomeFileName.java"
Click on "-" (Minus) button to remove pattern from the list
Repeat 1-2-3 for other undesired patterns

If desired, you can also do this manually by editing config file while IDE is closed. Because it's IDE-wide setting, it is not stored in .idea folder (which has project settinsg only) -- the file to look for is called filetypes.xml and shoudl be located in ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdeaXX/options ( see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181 for other OS etc )