# Cannot create java file in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I cannot create java class file with name `TokenProperties.java`. I also tried restart and clean cache but doesn't help. Class with different name I can crate.

Here is error pop-up.

[image]

File will added but marked as plain text file, and no java file.

[image]

Do you have idea whats is going on? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you try to create the file in the project?

Comment: @Jason I updated question. I tried add next to main class

Comment: The packaging is correct. It kind of looks like you create a TXT file with the name *TokenProperties.java* when you want to create a JAVA file with the name *TokenProperties* similar to how DemoAAplication was created.

Comment: @DenisStephanov See if [disabling](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) TextMate bundles plug-in helps.

Comment: @DenisStephanov check whether [filetype](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html) .java file  extension was mapped to the wrong file type.

Comment: @JosePraveen thank you for effort but I have to reinstalled idea and now it works

Comment: @DenisStephanov similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59651102/8035260) but fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of looks like you create a TXT file with the name TokenProperties.java when you want to create a JAVA file with the name TokenProperties similar to how DemoAAplication was created.

1. Right click com.example.demoa package.
2. Select **New**
3. Select **Java Class**

Comment: I did it like you said.

Comment: Did it work? If not, did it produce the same problem? Did you get rid of the TokenProperties.java file?

Comment: I've created java class file. Also when I create class named Token it is fine, but when I change name to TokenProperties then file type is changed and I don't know why.

Comment: Likely because IntelliJ has cached the name TokenProperties and expects it to be a TXT file now. Not sure how IntellIJ handles it but search for TokenPropertues in /.idea/ in your project root directory and you'll probably find it.

Comment: I have to reinstalled idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix it so I reinstalled Intellij and now it works.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13374653/104891. This file name was mapped to text files.